# How to fix the checking of user access in the master page of this asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am new ASP.NET developer and right now I am working on the User-Role mechanism of the application. The application should be only accessible 
by the people who belong to specific groups. Then, the system should check the role of each user. Some of the menu options will
be hidden based on the roles. If the user belongs to a group which can't access the system, then the user should be redirected to
'Access Denied' Page. Note that all the pages including the 'Access Denied' page is using the MasterPage to get the same look and feel.

As I am using ASP.NET Menu control, I wrote a method for hiding the menu item options based on the role of the user. However, I am still 
struggling with redirecting the users, who belong to a group which can't access the system, to the 'Access Denied' page. **When I debug
my following code, the debugger when through an infinite loop of checking the access and setting the menu items.**

So how can I fix this problem?

**Code-Behind of the MasterPage.master:**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuAccess();
    }


    protected void MenuAccess()
    {
        if (HasAccess())
        {
            if (!Helper.IsAdmin(username))
            {
                MenuItemCollection menuItems = NavigationMenu.Items;
                RemoveMenuItemByValue(menuItems, "movies");
            }
            if (!Helper.IsSupport(username))
            {
                MenuItemCollection menuItems = NavigationMenu.Items;
                RemoveMenuItemByValue(menuItems, "music");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Error/AccessDenied.aspx");
            return;
        }
    }

    protected bool HasAccess() 
    {
        bool hasAccess = false;
        //General access to the system by the group code
        if (Helper.HasAccess(orgCode))
        {
            hasAccess = true;
        }
        return hasAccess;
    }


    public static void RemoveMenuItemByValue(MenuItemCollection items, String value)
    {
        MenuItem itemToRemove = null;

        //Breadth first, look in the collection
        foreach (MenuItem item in items)
        {
            if (item.Value == value)
            {
                itemToRemove = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (itemToRemove != null)
        {
            items.Remove(itemToRemove);
            return;
        }

        //Search children
        foreach (MenuItem item in items)
        {
            RemoveMenuItemByValue(item.ChildItems, value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you do your checks in the MasterPage and because

> Note that all the pages including the 'Access Denied' page is using
>   the MasterPage to get the same look and feel.

Then, when you redirect to "Access Denied", you are again checking if they have permissions.

So, either give everyone permissions to "AccessDenied" or add a special if condition to not check if that is the page.

Or, you can not use the MasterPage for "AccessDenied".

For example, in your code ...

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //If this page is not AccessDenied.aspx
    if(Request.Path != "~/Pages/Error/AccessDenied.aspx")
    {
        MenuAccess();
    }
}
```

Comment: @TechnologyLover The code snippet provided probably does not work, but you would do something similar ...

Comment: I didn't get the idea as I am still a new developer. Could you please help me within my code?

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, but if there is any adjustment that I can do to my code, then it will be much better and helpful to me.

Comment: @TechnologyLover I did showed you within your code. Just add the if condition to your Page_Init method like in the answer.

Comment: you did not get the point of my code: My code will start with the MenuAccess() method and from there, it will go to check if the user has access or not based on his groupCode. If his group is not in the database, then he should be redirected to the Access Denied page.

Comment: I put that condition in the Page_Init method, and now everybody can access the system even if his group doesn't have an access